# How can I print the contents of stack in C program?

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, x86

I want to, as the title says, print the contents of the stack in my C program.

Here are the steps I took:

- I made a simple assembly (helper.s) file that included a function to return the address of my ebp register and a function to return the address of my esp register

  ```
  .globl get_esp

  get_esp:
      movl %esp, %eax
      ret
  # get_ebp is defined similarly, and included in the .globl section
  ```
- I called the `get_esp ()` and `get_ebp ()` functions from my C program ( `fpC = get_esp ();` where fpC is an int)
- I (successfully, I think) printed the address of my esp and ebp registers ( `fprintf (stderr, "%x", fcP);` )
- I tried, and failed to, print out the contents of my esp register.  (I tried `fprintf (sderr, "%d", *fcP);` and `fprintf (sderr, "%x", *((int *)fcP));`, among other methods). My program hits a segmentation fault at runtime when this line is processed.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This must be accomplished by calling these assembly functions to get the stack pointers.
EDIT2: This is a homework assignment.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it failed?  What output did you get and what did you expect?

Comment: To print pointers, you must use `printf("%p", (void*)(p))`. The "content of %esp" is a pointer.

Comment: @CarlNorum: No, the `printf` use is simply mandated by the C standard. (Cf. "variadic arguments".)

Comment: Another simple way in C is to just look at the address of a local variable (&localvar), and print out the adjacent values if you want to view the stack.

Comment: @TJD: Not all local variables live on the stack.

Comment: When I say it failed, I mean I get a segmentation fault during runtime.

Comment: @dreamlax, but it's easy to make one that does.

Answer (score 5):

If your utilising a GNU system, you may be able to use GNU's extension to the C library for dealing backtraces, see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html).

```
#include <execinfo.h>

int main(void)
{
     //call-a-lot-of-functions
}

void someReallyDeepFunction(void)
{
    int count;
    void *stack[50]; // can hold 50, adjust appropriately
    char **symbols;

    count = backtrace(stack, 50);
    symbols = backtrace_symbols(stack, count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        puts(symbols[i]);

    free(symbols);
}
```

Comment: That looks like a fine way to go about it, but I need to implement this using the assembly functions (per assignment requirements). I should have specified that in my problem originally.

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited original post.

Answer (score 4):

`get_esp` returns `esp` as it is within the function. But this isn't the same as `esp` in the calling function, because the call operation changes `esp`.

I recommend replacing the function with a piece of inline assembly. This way `esp` won't change as you try to read it.

Also, printing to `sderr` wouldn't help. From my experience, `stderr` works much better.